# Displaying score from sql android using textview

Tags: android, sql, textview

Ok so im trying to make highscore for my app, and i am not sure how to make strings that contain date, score and name(they are already in sql, now i need to pull them out) appear in textview

```
    public String[] getAllScores(){

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE + "LIMIT 10";



        SQLiteDatabase hs = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = hs.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        int i = 0;

        String[] data = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            data[i] = cursor.getString(1);

            i = i++;

        }
        cursor.close();
        hs.close();
        // return score array
        return data;
    }
```

}

Activity to display score

```
Highscore hs=new Highscore(this);
     hs.addScore(name, currentDTS, scukupno);
     hs.getAllScores();
     TextView score1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rezultat);
     score1.setText( What to write here???? );
```

Comment: what are the fields actually in the table? You try to select all the values.. But your question was "How to make a string contains date, score and name). Make the question clear?

Comment: Please refer to my answer below and let me know. Best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should print everything in the **score1** if you want.

You can use :

```
String[] stringArray = hs.getAllScores();
String tempString = "";
    for(String string:stringArray){
tempString = tempString+string;//this will give you a string with all string
    }
score1.setText(tempString);//this will set the textView with everything
```

But you may want to give a white space or dash or anything in between them to make it clear.

Just put `tempString = tempString + "-";` after `tempString = tempString+string;` line

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using TextUtils.join ?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Iterable%29

```
String[] stringArray = hs.getAllScores();
score1.setText(TextUtils.join("-", stringArray));
```

replace "-" with whatever you want to use.